# convert child collection's _id to string using $set

Tags: mongodb

This is how my documents look like:

```
Category:

_id:5f471cfb40868e7859587054
cat_name:"some category"
resource_owner:"test"


Item:
_id:5f471cfb40868e7859587044
item_name:"awesome item 1"
resource_owner:"test"

_id:5f471cfb40868e7859587099
item_name:"awesome item 2"
resource_owner:"test"
```

I am writing aggregation to fetch the records from these collections using `$lookup` and `$set` to convert `_id` to string. It works for the parent collection (Category) but does not work with child collection `Item`.

Here is how my aggregate pipeline looks like:

```
[
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'item', 
            'localField': 'resource_owner', 
            'foreignField': 'resource_owner', 
            'as': 'products'
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {
            '_id': ObjectId('5f471cfb40868e7859587054')
        }
    }, {
        '$set': {
            '_id': {
                '$toString': '$_id'
            }, 
            'products._id': {
                '$toString': '$_id' <--this sets parent's _id to child's _id
            }
        }
    }
]
```

How do I modify the above `$set` to convert child collection's _id to string possibly without using `$unwind`?

I am using `mongodb 4.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator,

```
  {
    "$set": {
      "_id": { "$toString": "$_id" },
      "products": {
        $map: {
          input: "$products",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              { _id: { $toString: "$$this._id" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cFIeIGDpQoN)